# Seeking vectorized solution to sum up elements using accumarray in Matlab/Numpy

Tags: matlab, vectorization

(To anyone who reads this, just to not waste your time, I wrote up this question and then came up with a solution to it right after I wrote it. I am posting this here just to help out anyone who happened to also be thinking about something like this.)

I have a vector with elements that I would like to sum up. The elements that I would like to add up are elements that share the same "triggerNumber". For example:

```
vector        = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
triggerNumber = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

I will sum up the numbers that share a triggerNumber of 1 (so 0+1+1 =2) and share a triggerNumber of 2 (so 1+1+1 = 3). Therefore my desiredOutput is the array [2, 2].

accumarray accomplishes this task, and if I give it those two inputs:

```
output = accumarray(triggerNumber.',vector.').'
```

which returns [2, 2]. But, while my "triggerNumbers" are always increasing, they are not necessarily always increasing by one. So for example I might have the following situation:

```
vector        = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
triggerNumber = [4, 4, 4, 6, 6]
output = accumarray(triggerNumber.',vector.').'
```

But now this returns the output:

```
output = [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2]
```

Which is not what I want. I want to just sum up elements with the same trigger number (in order), so the desired output is still [2, 2]. Naively I thought that just deleting the zeros would be sufficient, but then that messes up the situation with the inputs:

```
vector        = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
triggerNumber = [4, 4, 4, 6, 6]
```

which if I deleted the zeroes would return just [2] instead of the desired [0, 2].

Any ideas for how I can accomplish this task  (in a vectorized way of course)?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to turn things like [4, 4, 4, 6, 6] into [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], which can be done with a combination of cumsum and diff.

```
vector        = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1];
triggerNumber = [4, 4, 4, 6, 6];
vec1    = cumsum(diff(triggerNumber)>0);
append1 = [0, vec1];
magic = append1+1;
output = accumarray(magic.',vector.').'
```

which returns [2, 2]....and hopefully my method works for all cases.